# Is it possible to do real time analysis of data stored in MariaDB with help of Alibaba Quick BI?

Tags: mysql, cloud, mariadb, alibaba-cloud

I want to analyze the data stored in MariaDB in Real Time with the help of Quick BI, Is it possible to connect MariaDB with QuickBI? I also find no ETL Support for Quick BI. Also, there is no RDS support for MariaDB as of now and I am able to find it in the roadmap. Could anyone suggest me how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at Data Lake Analytics of Alibaba Cloud. The product is still in beta but launching soon. That might solve the requirement.

The crux of **Data Lake Analytics**:
Data Lake Analytics is a data analytics service that does not require any Extract-Transform-Load (ETL) tools but allows you to use standard SQL interface and business intelligence (BI) tools to cost-effectively and efficiently analyze data in the cloud.

You can find more detail here : https://www.alibabacloud.com/products/data-lake-analytics